# DBRefs (Mongo Document references) not fetched eagerly

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-document

I am using Mongo in its simplest avatar possible (in conjunction with Spring Data).

I have two (first class) entities (@Documents) A and B, where A has a reference (@DBRef) of B within it. Everything works fine when creating A and B. However, when reading object A (by Id), the reference B is always **null**.

I believe DBRefs are eagerly fetched by default (see http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-document/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-usage-references), but the behavior currently is against that. Any ideas why?

Comment: I have the same problem with RC1.
Through the shell I see the correct dbref , but when loading the refernce is always null.
Did you upgrade the lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving over to the Spring Data Mongo M5 build resolved this. So, must be a bug until then.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, any DBRefs are eagerly fetched, but they are not eagerly saved (AFAIK). If A has a reference to B, when you save A, Spring Data/MongoDB doesn't automatically save B, you have to.

```
// Incorrect, upon retrieval a.getB() == null
A a = new A();
a.setB(new B());
repositoryA.save(a);

// Correct (to the best of my knowledge)
B b = repositoryB.save(new B());
A a = new A();
a.setB(b);
repositoryA.save(a);
```

Comment: yes, I seemed to have figured that out. What I am now looking for is a way/pattern to fetch the referenced objects. So, you can fetch 'A' using findOne(a_id), but how do you fetch B?

Comment: It ought to be there when you fetch A, just as you were expecting.  I don't know of any reason (besides the one in my answer) that A should contain a null reference to B.  Have you tried using the `mongo` command line client to connect to the server and run a query?  Then you can see whether the DBRef to B is present in any objects A.